# How does django settings tied to web application

Tags: python, django

Suppose i my web application running with following settings

```
LOG_DIR = "/var/log/main"
```

This variable defines where the log should go.

Now then i run my tests  and i have test_settings like

```
from settings import *
LOG_DIR = "/var/log/test"
```

Now i want to know that does that mean while my test script is running then my main application logs will also go to test folder because i have chnaged the global variable.

For my integration testiing i need to change variables if am afraid that if that will affect the main application or not .Like my application depends upon

Shell ENV variables . I wanted to chnage that for my tests. but i am afraid that if that will chnage the main running application.

This is not for PROD but for other testing applications environment

Comment: When you run your tests with something like `manage.py test --settings settings.test` it's a completely separate process than when you run your application as a server. Regarding setting env variables, they are per-shell, so you can have them set up for testing in one shell and it wont affect other shells. You might want to create some form of test runner that configures the environment variable and then runs manage.py test in the testing configration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a django process will not affect the settings of another process. Just make sure to explicitly pass the `--settings` flag to your `manage.py` script when you run your tests/dev server/ etc..

e.g.

```
python manage.py test --settings project/settings/test.py
python manage.py runserver --settings project/settings
```

I prefer having a set of shell scripts that get sourced when I run my test environment (you can configure that with a test runner, see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/advanced/)).